# ubuntu 13.10 - language toggle keys don't work

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

I've read some people have been having trouble with switching between languages and I'm also experience something similar. In my case I can successfully change the key combination to switch languages and it works at first, however, after some time it no longer works. Going to "text entry settings" there seems nothing wrong. I can fix it by re entering the desired key combination but again after some time it "forgets it" and no longer works.

This is a fresh install of ubuntu 13.10.

Any help appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that works:

1. I put `setxkbmap -option grp:ctrl_alt_toggle us,el` in a text file
2. click `super` key search for `startup` click on `startup aplications`
3. Click add then browse, then look for the script and enter `bash` at the beggining of the command entry so you have something like `bash /home/user/place/whereyou/saved/textfilename.sh`
4. Restart and check that it works

Problems with this:

1. It doesn't update the icon showing which language is selected

Answer (score 0):

A guess: The problem might be that the combination you select conflicts with a keyboard shortcut used by some other part of the system, e.g. Unity. You may want to try some other combination.

Comment: I've tried different combinations and it doesn't matter. Also, I don't understand why it would change after some time? The current combination I'm trying is ALT+super

Comment: What if you avoid Super, and use e.g. Ctrl+Shift L?

Comment: if I use this then I can't do cltr+shift+arrow to select multiple words... although it is toggling languages for now

Comment: @evan54: Ok. For me the default Super+Space does not work in 13.10, but it does in 14.04, so I have a feeling that 13.10 is buggy in this respect.